# Objectify query by list having all elements of a sublist

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The next query returns all records that SomeElement's aList contains **one of** aSubList elements:

```
ofy.query(SomeEntity.class).filter("aList in",aSubList);
```

What i need is a query that returns all records of SomeElement that its aList contains **all** of the elements in aSubList (and not just one of them)

Any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you seem to be using the syntax for a several-year-old version of Objectify. Please upgrade.

Then this should work:

```
ofy().load().type(SomeEntity.class)
    .filter("aList", thing1)
    .filter("aList", thing2)
    ...
```

If you are iterating in a loop, don't forget to reassign the query value since Objectify commands are functional:

```
query = query.filter("aList", thing);
```